# Python3 cv2 and matplotlib import cause error

Tags: python, numpy, qt, opencv, matplotlib

It seems when I try and use matplotlib and cv2 I get a weird QT error. I don't know what's causing it, here is how it looks:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x560dde045c50) is not the object's thread (0x560dde1a5030).
Cannot move to target thread (0x560dde045c50)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx.

./ex1.sh: line 3: 43764 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./ex1/main.py
```

I have no clue what is causing this but it's always when I try and call plt.plot() which is the first time I use matplotlib in my script.